# Как использовать функцию partial?

Tags: python

Пытаюсь решить задачу (https://stepik.org/lesson/63306/step/8)

> Напишите функцию con_class, которая принимает целое положительное число n и возвращает итерируемый объект (iterable), содержащий все делящиеся на n целые числа в промежутке от 0 до 100 (обе границы включены).
>
> Определите эту функцию в терминах другой функции как частично применённую (имеется ввиду, что вам не понадобится создавать свою функцию, а потом ее уже частично применять к чему-то --- достаточно обратиться к какой-то встроенной функции).

```
Примеры ожидаемого поведения


for num in con_class(101):

    print(num)

0 # из чисел 0, 1, 2, ..., 100 только 0 делится на 101
```

Какую встроенную функцию имел ввиду автор? divmod?
Мое решение ниже

```
from functools import partial

con_class = partial(divmod, 101, n=int(input()))
```

```
Failed test #1 of 90. Runtime error

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 6, in <module>
    print(list(con_class(int(input()))))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from functools import partial

con_class = partial(range, 0, 101)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import partial

con_class = partial(divmod, 101, n=int(input()))
```

- Во-первых вы не должны использовать `input` в своей функции, ваша функция должна просто принимать аргумент обычным образом в скобочках `con_class(n)`. Именно использованием `input` вызвана ошибка `EOFError: EOF when reading a line` - вы таким образом забрали ввод, который предназначался для проверочной обвязки, которая проверяет работу вашей функции
- Вы должны передать в `partial` саму функцию, а также какую-то часть её аргументов. При этом у функции `divmod` нет именованных аргументов вообще и в частности аргумента `n=`, так что вы написали что-то непонятное. `101` передастся первым аргументом в `divmod`, а с `n=` будет ошибка.
- На самом деле я тоже не очень понимаю, что они от вас хотели в этой хитрой формулировке, но в любом случае то, что вы написали, не выполняет задачу фильтрации чисел по условию задач. Попробуйте сначала решить задачу не обращая внимание на эту формулировку, просто хоть как-нибудь. А потом уже можно будет подумать, как туда применить `partial` или `lambda`, например.